# CHKDSK Unspecified error occurred (766f6c756d652e63 470)

Tags: lenovo-laptop, chkdsk, bad-sectors

I've got a problem with a Lenovo laptop that sometimes it can boot to Windows and mostly it just hang at the Lenovo logo. I tried to boot from USB and did a `chkdsk /b /v /f /scan c:` and following is the result:
[image]

It seems to have some bad sectors on the drive.

I tried to do a system restore by using the OneKey Recovery and sometimes it can work and sometimes it does not even load the recovery screen, causing me unable to restore the Windows.
And when I was able to restore, after installing Windows, it will just hang there.

1. What does this unspecified error means?
2. Is there anything that I can do beside replacing the HDD?
3. Is there any other problem beside the HDD?

Comment: 1. It means a non specific error; 2. No; 3. Maybe.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered similar problem. Mine was:

`CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
  394752 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  12 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  0 EA records processed.
  0 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
67 percent complete. (430369 of 498700 index entries processed)
An unspecified error occurred (696e647863686b2e e19).`

I google whole web and found nothing useful.
So I started checking drive manually. Indexes are directories in NTFS, so I started checking their contents. I found out old backup which have files with russian characters in names. Non unicode applications (like console and Altap Salamander) cannot show the characters and display just '?' instead. Unicode ready application (like Total Commander) show a warning when you enter a directory with files like these. So I just run Windows Explorer and I simply deleted this old backup with non-english character file names.

Afterwards, chkdsk runs normally. Maybe it helps somebody.

`CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
  394752 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  12 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  0 EA records processed.
  0 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
  496480 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered.
CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
  394752 file SDs/SIDs processed.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  50865 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  541649592 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.`